# Bind form.serialize() as custom object

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send an AJAX post to an MVC action result and pass a custom object (`ContactInformationModel`) over as the parameter for the action result. However the expected type of the parameter is apparently not correct because the parameter is always null. I thought this was possible but maybe it's not?

My action result is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateContactInformation(ContactInformationModel model)
    {
         ...
    }
```

My jQuery:

```
    //Serialize the ContactInformationModel object 
    var formData = $('#frmSubmitContactInformation').serialize();

    // Submit ajax call
    $.ajax({
            url: "/api/[Redacted]/UpdateContactInformation",
            type: "POST",
            data: { model: formData },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    alert('success');
                } else {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            }
    });
```

My markup (ASP.NET MVC View):

```
@model [Redacted].Output.ContactInformationModel

<form id="frmSubmitContactInformation">
    Add contact information to your project <button type="button" class="strip-button js-contact-launch js-edit-toggle"><span class="icon icon-edit"></span></button> <button class="btn btn--small btn--green add-half-left-margin js-submit-btn-contactinfo js-contact-launch js-edit-toggle hidden" type="submit">@Translation.Text("done")</button>
    @*Done Button*@
    <div class="js-contact-drawer hidden">
        <div class="reveal-output__form column column--no-vert-padding add-half-bottom-margin add-half-top-margin form-group">
            <div class="content-block">
                @* First/Last/Company Name *@
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.FirstName,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.LastName,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CompanyName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyName,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.CompanyName,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-block">
                @* Email/Phone *@
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmailAddress,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.EmailAddress,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhoneNumber,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.PhoneNumber,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-block">
                @* Address 1/Address 2 *@
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address1)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address1,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.Address1,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address2)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address2,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.Address2,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-block">
                @* City/State/Zip*@
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.City,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.State)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.State, AddressHelper.GetUnitedStatesListItems(), Translation.Text("state"), new {@class = "custom-select"})
                </div>
                <div class="content-block__third-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PostalCode)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PostalCode)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PostalCode,
                        new
                        {
                            @Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.PostalCode,
                            @class = "form-control"
                        })
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="ProjectId" value="@Model.ProjectId" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm positive that the class referenced in the view is the exact same as I am referencing in the controller. Also, the JS runs fine itself. What could be the issue?

Comment: Its just `data: formData;` (`formData` is already the correct serialized object)

Comment: Side note - never attempt to set the `value` attribute (and your `@Value = Model == null ? "" : Model.PostalCode,` is doing nothing anyway, so remove them) - the `HtmlHelper` methods will always set the correct value, and the only possible outcome is to make model binding fail

Comment: D'oh. Let me try just using data: formData. And for the other thing, what is a better way of setting a default value in the view?

Comment: The `HtmlHelper` methods are already setting the correct `value` attributes based on your mdoel properties. If you have not passed a model to the view, or have passed a new default instance, then it will generate `value=""` for your string properties. If you pass a model that has say, `model.FirstName = "Paul"`, then it will generate `value="Paul"`

Comment: Thank you Steve. Your data: formData fix worked - the object is not null and has all the field values. Please post it as a new answer. I will accept yours (since you answered first). I had no idea about the values automatically being pulled in, so thanks! I will remove those @Value calls.

Comment: An correct answer has already been added, so just accept that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul,

The issue is your data object. You need to directly post your serialized form object as data.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/[Redacted]/UpdateContactInformation",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success) {
                alert('success');
            } else {
                alert('fail');
            }
        }
});
```